# Execute Pyunit test on STAX Monitor

Tags: java, python, selenium-webdriver, stax

I have a problem to run my Junit test or Pyunit test on STAX Monitor . How can i execute my test in XML to use that on STAX Monitor.

````
<!DOCTYPE stax SYSTEM "stax.dtd">
<stax>
</script>
    <defaultcall function="main"/>
    <function name="main">
        <process name="'My Test Process'">
                <location>'local'</location>
                <command>'python'</command>
                <parms>cmdline</parms>
                <env>'C:\Users\X1>python -m unittest discover C:\Users\X1\test2 RegisterEmployeeTestRunner.py'</env>
                <stderr mode="'stdout'"/>
                <returnstdout/>
        </process>
    </function>
</stax>```
````

Comment: I have the same problem.1/ Start your Pyunit test on cmd `code` python -m unittest discover C:\Users\anthony\Desktop\test\RegisterEmployee.py `code`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE stax SYSTEM "stax.dtd">
<stax>
</script>
 <defaultcall function="main"/>
 <function name="main">
  <process name="'My Test Process'">
    <location>'local'</location>
    <command>'python'</command>
    <parms>cmdline</parms>
    <env>'C:\Users\x>python -m unittest discover C:\Users\x\test2\RegisterEmployee RegisterEmployeeTestRunner.py'</env>
    <stderr mode="'stdout'"/>
    <returnstdout/>
  </process>
 </function>
</stax>

Answer (score 0):

IN CMD RUN your test

> python -m unittest discover C:\Directory yourPyUnittest.py

Answer (score 0):

the XML to run your Punit test on STAX MONITOR

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE stax SYSTEM "stax.dtd">
<stax>
    <defaultcall function="FunctionA"/>
        <function name="FunctionA">
            <process>
                <location>'local'</location>
                <command>'python'</command>
                <parms>'C:\Users\x>python -m unittest discover C:\Users\x\test2\RegisterEmployee RegisterEmployeeTestRunner.py'</parms>
            </process>
        </function>
    </stax>```
````